# Matching features points of rotate image using SURF

Tags: computer-vision

I'm trying to match SURF points between 2 images using SURF with opencv. One is the rotation of the other.
The problem is that the few matching it can found are wrong.

[image of matching points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkW7V.jpg)

I mainly took my code from opencv http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#feature-flann-matcher

Here is the code:

```
string imageName1="test_right_rotate.jpg";
string imageName2="test_right.jpg";
Mat image1 = imread( imageName1, 1 );
Mat image2 = imread( imageName2, 1 );
int minHessian = 500;
SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

detector->detect( image1, keypoints_1 );
detector->detect( image2, keypoints_2 );

SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

extractor.compute( image1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
extractor.compute( image2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_1,descriptors_2, matches, 2);
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;
for(int i = 0; i < min(descriptors_1.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
{
    if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
    {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
    }
}
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( image1, keypoints_1, image2, keypoints_2, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

It works well for scaled images and translated images but fails for rotated images.

EDIT:

I don't know what is wrong but instead of using SURF, I used ORB as detector and FREAK as extractor and it works a lot better. 
You can find the code on this SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491022/opencv-freak-fast-retina-keypoint-descriptor

Comment: As the code from opencv didn't work, I took a part from here http://robocv.blogspot.jp/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: SURF isn't completely rotation invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SURF Features are not completely rotation invariant.

In the [paper](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/journals.htm?issn=0305-6120&volume=38&issue=3&articleid=17048144&show=pdf&PHPSESSID=jtag65l2jba9s0h2khjq8vl665), they try to make SURF more robust to rotations by following the following methodology.

In order to improve the performance for rotation, the descriptors are based on multi-orientations. The many-to-many tentative correspondences are determined with a maximum distance. Hough transform is used to reject the mismatches and the affine parameters are computed with a least-squares solution.

The image matching algorithm shows a better performance for image rotation than the standard SURF and it succeeds in matching the image including repetitive patterns which will deteriorate the distinctiveness of feature descriptors.